QuTiP mcsolve TypeError: Incompatible dimensions when passing initial state
I'm trying to simulate the dynamics of an open quantum system using the mcsolve function from QuTiP,
mc = mcsolve(H, psi0, dt, [L1,L3], [op], ntraj = 5)

but I keep running into a TypeError regarding incompatible dimensions when running the code. Below is the error message:
TypeError: incompatible dimensions[[2, 2], [2, 2]], [[2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 1]]

I suspect the issue might be related to how the initial state psi0 is constructed
from qutip import rand_ket
def psi0(n_qubits):
    """ Creates a random pure state for an n-qubit system. """
    # Calculate the dimension of the Hilbert space
    dim = 2**(n_qubits)
    
    # Create a random column vector and normalize it
    psi_0 = rand_ket(dim)
    
    return psi_0

or how the operators L1 and L3 are constructed
from qutip import mcsolve,Qobj, tensor, sigmax, sigmay, sigmaz, qeye
# Define the Gamma values (dissipation rates)
nsite = 2
Gamma1 = 0.1
Gamma2 = 0.1
Gamma3 = 0.1
Gamma4 = 0.1

# Define spin operators for Lindblad terms
sigmap = (sigmax() + 1j * sigmay()) * 0.5
sigmam = (sigmax() - 1j * sigmay()) * 0.5

# Define identity matrices for tensor products
identity_nsite_1 = qeye(2 ** (nsite - 1))
identity_nsite_2 = qeye((2**nsite/2))
identity_nsite_3 = qeye(2**((nsite/2)-1))


# Construct Lindblad operators
L1 = Gamma1 * tensor(sigmap, identity_nsite_1)
L3 = Gamma3 * tensor(identity_nsite_2, sigmap, identity_nsite_3)

I tried to print out the dimensions of the operators (H, L1, L3, op) and the wavefunction (psi0), they all seem to be consistent. Here’s the output for their dimensions:
Dimension of H: (4, 4); Dimension of L1: (4, 4); Dimension of L3: (4, 4); Dimension of op1: (4, 4); Dimension of psi0: (4, 1)

Despite this, the error persists. I expected the code to run without errors because the dimensions seemed to match correctly.
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
